# Getting median based on names and time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, median

Assume I have a dataframe:

```
 ID              Timestamp   Temp     Height
 01    2016-01-01 09:00:00     17         10
 01    2016-01-01 10:15:00     20          5
 02    2019-05-23 07:30:00     12          3
 01    2012-01-01 09:00:00     15         12
 01    2018-01-01 09:00:00     13         18
 02    2013-11-23 17:40:00     22          9
```

What I want is to get the median value of column 'Height' based on 'ID', & month & hour from 'Timestamp'. An example of my desired output:

```
 ID    Month     Hour     Height_median
 01       01       09                12
 01       01       10                 5
 02       05       07                 3
 02       11       17                 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(ID=[1,1,2,1,1,2], 
                  Timestamp=['2016-01-01 09:00:00','2016-01-01 10:15:00','2019-05-23 07:30:00',
                            '2012-01-01 09:00:00','2018-01-01 09:00:00','2013-11-23 17:40:00'],
                  Height = [10,5,3,12,18,9]))

df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)
df['month'] = df.Timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.month)
df['hour'] = df.Timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.hour)
df.groupby(['ID','month','hour'])[['Height']].agg('median').reset_index()
```